# stop music IMMEDIATELY

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation

Hi i have an app where you have to hold down a button and blow into the phone and it makes a sound, here is the code:

```
      #import "AirInstrumentViewController.h"

@implementation AirInstrumentViewController
    @synthesize audiOfA;
       - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
      {
/ / Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

   #pragma mark - View lifecycle



       - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];


     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
} else
    NSLog([error description]); 
}

          -  (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
[recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

if (lowPassResults > 0.55) {
    NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");

    if (aIsBeingTouched == YES) {
        NSString *musicString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"aifc"];
        audiOfA = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicString] error:NULL];
        [audiOfA play];

    } }else {

        [audiOfA stop];
    }


}

   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(aImage.frame, touchLocation)) {

    aImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"active.png"];
    aIsBeingTouched = YES;

          }
         }
             -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 [audiOfA stop];

aImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];

aIsBeingTouched = NO;

     }

- (void)viewDidUnload
     {

[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
   }



    @end
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do. Over here:
if (lowPassResults > 0.55) {
    NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");

```
if (aIsBeingTouched == YES) {
    NSString *musicString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"aifc"];
    audiOfA = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicString] error:NULL];
    [audiOfA play];

} }else {

    [audiOfA stop];
}


  }
```

The sound goes on for a BIT longer and then stops. same for the touches ended. And if i blow 
while not holding the image down, when i finally do hold the image down, it plays even though im not blowing because i blowed when it wasnt held down and it might have recorded it or SOMETHING! I dont know how to  fix all these problems please help!

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimer`'s are very unreliable. According to the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), quote:

> the effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100 milliseconds

It may be that since you are calling them so quickly (0.03 seconds or 30 milliseconds is pretty fast), the `NSTimer` is not getting called at the exact intervals, and therefore, it is skipping.

You may want to try multithreading this so that everything that is `UI`-related is done on the main thread, and the `AVAudio` parts are done on a separate thread. [This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/03/04/iphone-coding-turbo-charging-your-apps-with-nsoperation/) is a link explaining `NSOperation`'s, which is an easy way to do this, and should work well for you given the code you provided.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: i dont understand how that link can help me

Comment: the actual music stops like a second later though

Comment: Because you can use the `NSOperation` for the `AVAudio` sections so that the process is done on a separate thread, and will therefore speed up the main thread, and improve the timing of all you `NSTimer`'s as well as touch events, and other UI elements.

Comment: can you give me the code with an explanation i looked at the reference but i cant understnad it im sorry